# When we url encode (") will become (%22), is there any way we can decode (")?

Tags: xss, encoding

While studying the XSS vulnerability, I encountered a significant doubt. I noticed that when we include `"` in a URL, it gets encoded as `%22`. Therefore, I believe we can utilize the decoded version of `"`, ensuring it remains as `"` even after URL encoding. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It is worth a try but there is no guarantee that this actually works. In most cases it likely will not work.

Comment: "I believe we can utilize the decoded version of ", ensuring it remains as " even after URL encoding" -- why do you believe that?

Comment: hi @schroeder, As I'm unsure about how to bypass this protection, I've noticed that anything I pass through the URL gets encoded in some form. That's why I believe if we attempt to reverse this process, we might be able to bypass these restrictions.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why do you think that you can "reverse the process"? So far, it looks like a wild guess, not an informed theory. And what, exactly do you want to do? Can you give an example of what you think will work? Are you thinking that if you send `%22foo%22` the system will convert it into `"foo"`?

Comment: This varies a bit by browser, and where the character appears. For example (and just from memory), IE encodes the path portion, but not the query string. Also, there can be a difference between entering a URL in the address bar, and following a link. In general, this is worth reporting on a pen test. Bug bounties may have some limits around this and not accept IE-only XSS.